# Regex for Number "05XXXXXXXX"

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

Hi I need to check the input string using Regex for Number as "05XXXXXXXX" which must be start with '05' only and must be 10 digits.

I tried this;

```
^(?:[1-9]|0[1-9]|5[0-9]|0[0-9]|10)$
```

Thanks

Comment: I've always found [Regex Hero](http://regexhero.net) to be very useful for crafting RegEx expressions. It's free to use, if you don't mind occasional nuisances.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
^05[0-9]{8}$
```

Comment: Is 0500000000 a legal string? Does it match this expression?

Comment: Fixed :) I was a bit hasty in copy and paste changes

Answer (score 9):

You can simply use `{}` to specify a set repetition, e.g. something like this:

```
^05\d{8}$
```

- `^` matches the beginning of the string.
- `05` will be a simple and plain exact match.
- `\d` will match any digit.
- `{8}` will repeat the previous expression (`\d` in this case) exactly 8 times.
- `$` matches the end of the string.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
^05\d{8}$
```

That's "a 0 character, a 5 character, and and digit character repeated exactly 8 times."

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one too :

```
^0[5][0-9]{8}$
```

Hope it's help !

Comment: It is a habit if I have to update :) 
05[0-9]{8} works fine too !